# Formatting iOS with Cordova

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova, platform

currently I am creating an application using the Cordova engine plugin and angularJS library. I have created an app in both Android and iOS and everything seems okay in Android but for iOS, its a different story.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQKFE.png

Notice how on the select field (where it saids Show Everyone currently)? Notice how it wraps the text around when it hits the edge of the line? It doesn't seem to do this with Android or the web browser I have been testing with. I have thought of an alternative to prevent this issue by stacking everything on top of each other but I would like to have the style I have now?

My Question is there a way if the screen size is small, not to show all of the text in the select but instead the first few character ending in ...

Answer (score 0):

Try use something like this in the elements with have texts

```
@media (small-screen){
  .class-name{
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work sadly but it pointed me in the right direction so thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out Safari doesn't seem to use the word-wrap css tag by default by normal for select and option statements so I have added that and that seemed to do the trick to fix it. I am unsure if that means if they use Safari as the base for cordova apps however on iOS.